# Setup Xdebug configuration for PHP scripts called in cron by docker-entrypoint.sh in VSCode

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, cron, xdebug

Currently using VSCode on MacOS, Xdebug is working well for my PHP web application ran with docker.

But I also have some PHP scripts that are called by the `docker-entrypoint.sh` as crons and I'd like to be able to debug them as well. I can't configure it properly, nothing happens when I set breakpoints while the crons are running.

Here is my launch.json configuration at the moment (all the codesource - web, scripts...- is under `myapp/app`) :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9001,
            "log": true,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/opt/myapp/app": "/Users/me/src/myapp/app"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9002,
            "log": true
        }
    ]
}
```

In my docker-compose.yml, I also have `PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED=true` for the web container and the cron container of course.

Any ideas / configuration examples to get the debug working for the PHP crons ?

Comment: First, are you sure that you have enabled XDEBUG in the `php.ini` file used by the PHP CLI ? Do `>php --ini` from the terminal and check which `php.ini` is being used

Comment: Second XDEBUG 3 (the newest) uses port 9003 by default

Comment: `PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED=true` isn't something that Xdebug knows about. Can you share your `docker-compose.yml` file too?

Comment: Also can we see the XDEBUG section of the `php.ini`

Comment: Oh yeah you were right @RiggsFolly, XDEBUG is enabled on the web container but not in the cron container, therefore I have to check the Dockerfile to enable it. I'm using XDEBUG 2 btw, which port is 9001 by default.

Here is my php.ini on the web container : 
`[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_autostart =  1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = dockerhost
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_port = 9001`

So if I have the same conf on the cron container it should work ? I assume I have to take another port ? 

Thanks !

Comment: Xdebug 2 is no longer supported, please upgrade.

Comment: But only if you are using a supported version of PHP. For XDEBUG3 you have to be using PHP7.2 or better

Comment: 1) To ensure that Xdebug is there and is configured -- make some PHP script that will be run by cron and call `phpinfo();` there. Then show the whole Xdebug section here. 2) If it's all there (live values equal to your configured values) -- enable Xdebug log. Then wait till it runs and see what the log will have there. Make sure that the file is writeable. Empty log can mean that Xdebug does not try to debug (does not see "debug me" flag & not configured to debug every single script). **P.S.** You can also add `xdebug_break();` in PHP code -- acts as a programmatic breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for all these answers. 
It's almost working now, there is just one small error that I need to solve, but a least xdebug is running. 
I now have the xdebug log with the following message : 
`[4245] W: Creating socket for 'dockerhost:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[4245] E: Could not connect to client. :-(`
It seems related to the X-Forwarded-For header or the xdebug.remote_host, I'll dig a bit more and it should be ok!